# Login Form Input Field Validation using PHP

Tags: php

Please tell me how validate a user input, for alphabets only.

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="form1">
<table>
<tr>
<td id="CA_Tbl_Title">Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="First_Name" onclick="make_blank_First();"    
autofocus="First_Name" id="Form_Input_User"
value="<?php echo $First_Name; ?>"/>
<span class="Error"><?php echo $Msg_First_Name; ?></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Come on ! No research effort ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

Comment: Please add what resources you have already looked at and where you're hanging.

Comment: You need effort more before to ask. Please elaborate more the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check `ctype_alpha` method.

```
bool ctype_alpha ( string $text )
```

Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are alphabetic. In the standard C locale letters are just `[A-Za-z]` and `ctype_alpha()` is equivalent to `(ctype_upper($text) || ctype_lower($text))` if `$text` is just a single character, but other languages have letters that are considered neither upper nor lower case.

Returns `TRUE` if every character in text is a letter from the current locale, `FALSE` otherwise.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php